# Jumping from Win10 to Linux

Tags: system-installation, 15.10, windows-10

So, I'm thinking about jumping from Win10 to Ubuntu 15.10. Now, I'm a bit of a noob, I've played around with Ubuntu on a VM but nothing too in-depth.

I've used Ubuntu and it runs quite nicely on my VM so it's definitely a good choice imo.

Quick edit: As a student Office is super useful, even though LibreOffice is also good but for Excel and etc I do think Office is the best choice. How does Wine handle it? About gaming does Wine give a good performance?

Where are my laptop's specs, if it helps:

```
Intel® Core™ i5-6200U Dual-Core 2.3 GHz
8GB ram 
HDD SATA 750GB
7200RPM 2.5" Intel® HD Graphics 520 + NVIDIA® GeForce® 940M with 2GB DDR3 VRAM
```

Comment: If you are planning to run most programmes via wine, moving from windows to linux will not be a nice experience. I personally would first try making the transition from MS Office to Libreoffice and then think about moving to linux. By the way I am a quite avid spreadsheet user (about 50% of my worktime consists of spreadsheets), and I do not think Excel has to offer that much more than Libreoffice calc. The only serious problem you will sometimes encounter are some incompatibilities with complicated xlsx files.

Comment: Ahah, true. I'll probably go with Ubuntu since I know it better, I just figured I'd ask because it is Ubuntu based.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question deals with wine (not Ubuntu) at all, plus discussing about the performance of wine is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: First rule: Linux is not Windows. And, hopefully (let's pray), it will never be. So if you plan doing everything through Wine, here's my suggestion: don't. Ubuntu is a different Operating System, in a whole different universe, and you'll have to get used to it: you do it, or you don't; there is no try. Train some LibreOffice madskillz, run native games (there are hundreds of great titles) and welcome to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Wine is good but not as pure windows, if you need need softwares that is not supported on Ubuntu why you should use one? Plus you already have windows installed.

But if you want Ubuntu for whatever reason, you can install it alongside windows and use them both, [here is the video link, about how to install it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOz66FC0pWU).

Ubuntu is pretty good, but Office is not one of the best side of it. Actually Ubuntu is good when you are beginner programmer, or web developer since it is open source and you can understand how everything works.

Although, Ubuntu is one of the best gaming linux distro, but not better then windows, at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 14.0.4 until 16.0.4 comes out as it is an LTS version and therefore more stable.

EDIT: At least for me (GTX650), Ubuntu 15.10 didn't play well with the Nvidia drivers. (Random graphical glitches, among others)

Office in Wine - depends on the version. (You could also use Office Online) For information on your specific version, Check out the [Wine HQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/)

Gaming in Wine - unless it's something like "Minesweeper," forget about it.

Comment: Office Online seems great, just tried it. LibreOffice also works well so if I really need Office to I can either user Office Online or on a VM. 

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will most definitely work on your computer.

I see a potential for issues with your graphics, as NVIDIA isn't stable on Ubuntu, but there's not much chance of failure. If you have any issues, do a quick search and you'll most likely find an answer. If not, ask a question here.

Unfortunately, Microsoft Office does not run in Wine. Trust me, I've tried; 2010, 2013 and 2016 all crash with some issue. It seems MS has done its best to stop Ubuntu users from using Office products. You'll have to dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows or settle for LibreOffice.

Gaming, judging from discussions on this site and on various forums, is a hit-and-miss situation. You might get great performance with one game and not with another. You might have terrible performance while someone else has amazing FPS. It seems mostly random, but go ahead and try.

As for the Ubuntu version: since you have NVIDIA, I'm going to suggest against following Android Dev's advice. 14.04, while LTS, does not have the newer drivers or kernel sometimes needed for NVIDIA graphics to work. Especially with newer cards, you'll want to get the latest version. Once 16.04 comes out, you can upgrade easily.

I hope this helped. Leave a comment with any questions.

Comment: I was also afraid the graphics card would cause some issues. It used to fail in firefox constantly so I had to settle for Chrome, I think it was the hardware acceleration that caused it to fail.

I think I might just go with dual-boot, at least in the beginning.

Comment: @QWERTYMurdoc Definitely a good choice. That way, if Ubuntu doesn't work out, you can just get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do . I use Ubuntu for most of my work . For things which runs best in Windows(such as Office , Games ) , I run them using VMWare. As you have 8 gigs of RAM , I don't think you'll face any problem running Windows parallely in a virtual environment. You can share the physical drive or locations with your guest OS , i.e. Windows and use those locations in a very normal manner . Once you get used to Ubuntu and it's customization capabilities , you'll never return to windows. Hope this helps in your transition.